# Joint distribution of linear combinations of independent Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability

Let $W_1, W_2,\cdots , W_{2n}$ be independent random variables s.t.

$$W_i =
\begin{cases}
0 \text{ w.p. 1/2} \\
1 \text{ w.p. 1/2}
\end{cases}
$$

for $1\leq i \leq 2n$.

> I am trying to check if the joint distribution of
> \begin{align}
> Y_1&:=W_1+W_{n+2} \\
> Y_2&:=W_2+W_{n+3} \\
> &\vdots \\
> Y_{n-1}&:= W_{n-1}+W_{2n} \\
> Y_{n}&:= W_n \\
> Y_{n+1}&:= W_{1}+W_{n+1}\\
> Y_{n+2}&:= W_2+W_{n+2} \\
> &\vdots \\
> Y_{2n}&:= W_n+W_{2n}
> \end{align}
> is uniform over $2^{2n}$ cases.

So for $n=2$, $Y_i's$ are $Y_1=W_1+W_4, Y_2=W_2, Y_3=W_1+W_3, Y_4=W_2+W_4$ and I've checked probabilities of all possible binary combinations of $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,Y_4$ and see that they are uniform over $2^4$ cases.

For $n=3$, $Y_i's$ are $Y_1=W_1+W_5, Y_2=W_2+W_6, Y_3=W_3, Y_4=W_1+W_4, Y_5=W_2+W_5, Y_6=W_3+W_6$ and I again manually verified that $Y_i's$ are uniform over $2^6$ cases. But I'm not sure how to prove for a general $n$ because it looks like a complicated set of linear combination of random variables? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your equations in matrix form as
$$
Y=AW\ ,
$$
where
\begin{align}
Y&=\pmatrix{Y_1\\Y_2\\\vdots\\Y_{2n}}\ ,\\
W&=\pmatrix{W_1\\W_2\\\vdots\\W_{2n}}\,\\
 A&=\pmatrix{I_{n\times n}&X_{n\times n}\\
I_{n\times n}&I_{n\times n}}\hspace{3em}\text{, and}\\
X_{n\times n}&=\pmatrix{0_{(n-1)\times1}&I_{(n-1)\times(n-1)}\\0_{1\times1}&0_{1\times(n-1)}}\ .
\end{align}
It's not hard to show that the matrix $\ A\ $ is invertible.  Therefore, the image $\ A\{0,1\}^{2n}\ $ of $\ \{0,1\}^{2n}\ $ has the same cardinality, $\ 2^{2n}\ $, as $\ \{0,1\}^{2n}\ $ itself, and if $\ y\in A\{0,1\}^{2n}\ $, then
$$
P(Y=y)=P\big(W=A^{-1}y\big)=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\ .
$$